# How to use relative links with a seperate header file?

Tags: php, relative-path, include-path, absolute-path

I am trying to use a separate header file with my website but have run into some problems with the links. Initially I had relative links for the navigation but after integrating my forum system, I was forced to switch to absolute links since the header was being included in sub directory files. Unfortunately, I now need to include a file via a relative link in order for it to work with my forums system due to a security feature that I can't change. If I try it with an absolute link, it simply returns a 403 error. Is there some way that I can have a "variable" relative path depending on the location of file that the header is included in? 
Thanks a bunch,
Josh

Here is my code:

Header:

```
    <? 
    session_start();
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
    include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_display.' . $phpEx);
    ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://192.168.1.29:8686/default.css"/>

<div class="headerMain">

    <div class="logo1">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="http://192.168.1.29:8686/images/favicon.jpg"></a>
            <div class="moto">

    </div>

    </div>


    <div class="navMain">

        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>

        <ul>
                <!--These are all the tabs at the top of the page <li><a href="link">title displayed on page</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="http://192.168.1.29:8686/index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://192.168.1.29:8686/projects.php">Projects</a></li>   <!-- if statement for selected navigation? -->
                <li><a href="http://192.168.1.29:8686/music.php">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://192.168.1.29:8686/blog.php">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://192.168.1.29:8686/forums/index.php">Forums</a></li>                         
    </ul>

    </div>

    <div class ="loginBox">

        <?php

         define('IN_PHPBB', true);
         $phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : 'http://192.168.1.29:8686/forums/';
         $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
         include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

         $user->session_begin();
         $auth->acl($user->data);

         $usrname = $user->data['username'];

         if($user->data['user_avatar']==null)
            {
             $avatar = "http://192.168.1.29:8686/forums/images/avatars/default.png";
            }
         else
            {
             $avatar = "http://192.168.1.29:8686/forums/download/file.php?avatar=".$user->data['user_avatar'];
            }

         if(!$user->data["is_registered"])
            {

         ?>

        <div class ="loggedOut">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://192.168.1.29:8686/forums/ucp.php?mode=login">Sign In</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://192.168.1.29:8686/forums/ucp.php?mode=register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>


        <div class ="loggedIn">

        <?php
        }

        else
        {
        echo "<div class='logged_in'>";

      echo "<div class='avatar'>";
                                         echo "<img src='$avatar' height='60px></div>";
                                    echo "</div>";

                                    echo "<div class='welcome'>";
                                         echo "<div class='welcome'>$usrname";
                                    echo "</div>";

                                    echo "<div class='log_links'>";        
                                        echo "<a href=\"forums/ucp.php\">My Account &nbsp </a>";    
                                        echo '<a href="forums/ucp.php?i=pm&folder=inbox">Messages('.$user->data["user_new_privmsg"].') &nbsp </a>';
                                        echo "<a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>";                                   
                                    echo "</div>";

                                echo "</div>";
                                }
                            ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```